# Pass entire row to a function in numpy vectorize in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have not used used numpy vectorization before. Here is a small example I am working.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def my_func(x, y):
    return x+y

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1, 100, 3), 'B': np.random.randint(1, 100, 3)})
>>> df
    A   B
0  97  58
1  78  64
2  53  25
```

My question is when dealing with a large dataset, is there a better way to pass columns to my user_func instead passing multiple columns? Is there any way to pass the whole row?

```
>>> df['result'] = np.vectorize(divide)(df['A'], df['B'])
>>> df
    A   B    result
0  97  58  1.672414
1  78  64  1.218750
2  53  25  2.120000
```

Comment: I don't get the hype around `np.vectorize`. It's just a glorified for loop. Why not `df['C'] = df['A']/df['B']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang as mentioned I am dealing with a huge dataframe and my functions are not as simple as adding two columns. Here only a small sample presented.

Comment: I don’t think it’s fair that you are asking people to redesign your function without knowing what it does or how it looks like. That said, for the most general case, you can do `apply` as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to manage a function on a row by row basis with `axis = 1`.

```
df['results'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_funct(x['A'],x['B']), axis = 1)
```

or

```
my_funct(row):
   return row['x'] + row['y']

df['results'] = df.apply(my_funct, axis = 1)
```

Though, I would expect passing the column to be faster. Utilizing Dask would also likely support you in a larger dataset if memory is an issue.